# How to access form inputs in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have such HTML:

```
<form data-bind="submit: mySubmit>
  <input type="text" ...
```

And I want to access the input's value upon submit:

```
mySubmit = function() {
  var textValue = ???;
  alert(textValue);
}
```

How can I do that ? I am OK with giving a kind of ID to the text field, but I don't want this ID to be global (for example I may have several of these forms on one page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at it from a Knockout perspective, then you really want to have the value of your input represented in your view model.  This would mean adding a `data-bind="value: myValue"` to your input.  Then, you would access it from the view model in your `mySubmit` method.

Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/sAyET

I would not recommend it, but the submit method is actually passed the form element in its first argument by Knockout (it really should be passed the current data and event, but currently it is the element).

So, you could do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/sAyET/1/.  Ideally, your view model should not have any references to the DOM/view in it, so I would not recommend this option, unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I went with the solution you suggest. I didn't think of it because I didn't need two-way binding, but it is so simple !